# nested type mapping in elasticsearch with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch, mapping

I am trying to map elasticsearch index, but I keep getting an error with nested type.

```
request_body = {
"setting": {
    "number_of_shards": 3,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
},

"mappings": {
    "examplecase": {
        "properties": {
            "id": {"index": "not_analyzed", "type": "string"},
            "source": {"index": "analyzed", "type": "string"},
            "categories": {"index": "analyzed", "type": "string"},
            "source_link": {"index": "analyzed", "type": "string"},
            "article_name": {"index": "analyzed", "type": "string"},
            "text": {"index": "analyzed", "type": "string"},
            "date": {"index": "analyzed", "type": "string"},
            "article_text": {"type": "nested", "properties":
                {"text":
                    {"type": "string"},
                 "paragraph_name": {"type": "string"}}
                },
            "language": {"index": "analyzed", "type": "string"}
        }
    }
}
}
es.indices.create(index="articles", body=request_body)
```

and I keep getting this error:

```
 'illegal_argument_exception', "object mapping [article_text] can't be 
 changed from nested to non-nested")
```

All the mapping looks like in the elasticsearch documentation, I do not know whats wrong.  Does anyone have any ideas ?

Comment: What is your ES version?

Comment: And you may already have this index. You can get this error when changing the mapping and types of fields. I guess, the problem is this.

Comment: First of all, I was getting success result, when I tried to execute your query on ES 5.4.3. The problem is you try to reindex your mapping to your index. In this situation, ES is trying to change your older mapped fields type. But there are some problems about this. You can check the article:

https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime